# Quinean Regex Tester

Tags: code-golf, quine, regular-expression

This challenge is pretty simple. As input, you take in a regular expression.

Then, you output a truthy/falsey of whether or not your source code matches the regular expression. It's that simple! Just two more things:

- No quine builtins; you may, however, access the code's source code by file IO, etc.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

### Example

If your source code was say, `abc`, an input of `a\wc` would return true and an input of `a\dc` would return false.

Comment: Example please?

Comment: Would accessing the file/textarea in which the code is contained in count as a builtin?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ no, that's fine.

Comment: For your example, would regex `a` return true or false?

Comment: 1. I don't think *just a BRE with simple character classes* is specific enough. What BRE features have to be supported? 2. `\d` is not special in BRE; it matches the character `d`. 3. Choosing a specific regex flavor restricts your challenge to languages that support it, and few languages support BRE. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Dennis I'm not sure how regex's and flavours and stuff work, BRE was a name someone recommended in chat, and I kind of went with it. What do you recommend so answers don't have to worry about flavor specific features.

Comment: I'd recommend leaving it up to the answerer. If language **x** uses regex flavor **y** by default, let it use that flavor in this challenge.

Comment: @Maltysen "Use whatever RegEx is native to the language, or, BRE"

Comment: @Dennis makes sense.

Comment: Must the regex match the entire source code, or can it match a substring of the source code?

Comment: @feersum substring (unless, of course, it uses `^$`)

Comment: @Maltysen Why don't you add a substring example to the question body?

Answer (score 14):

## Z shell, 12 bytes

```
grep "$@"<$0
```

Zsh conditionals understand only exit codes, and the scripts exits with 0 or 1 accordingly.

In addition, this prints a non-empty string (the source code) for a match and an empty one for a mismatch, which could be as truthy/falsy values in combination with `test`/`[`.

The program reads its own file, but according to [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69203/quinean-regex-tester#comment168459_69203) by the OP, this is allowed.

Comment: Aaand Dennis won. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This doesn't work. It breaks on patterns with spaces in them.

Comment: @feersum Whoops! Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Now it breaks if it is written to a file with spaces in the name. Or a file called `-v`. Or...

Comment: @BenMillwood I'd normally say *don't save it with such a file name*, but switching to zsh makes it bullet proof without incrementing the byte count.

Comment: I suppose you could also require the file to be called `a`, and then add +1 to the byte count (but `$0` --> `a` saves that byte, so it remains at 12 bytes). Becomes more portable, but less elegant.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), 39

```
(f=_=>!!`(f=${f})()`.match(prompt()))()
```

Comment: Just about to post this, but you beat me to it. Great job!

Comment: The beginning of your code looks like me when trying to understand this : (f=_=)

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3, 119 bytes

This just *looks* cooler, IMO (and it doesn't read the file).

```
(lambda i:print(bool(__import__('re').search(input(),i))))("(lambda i:print(bool(__import__('re').search(input(),i))))")
```

---

## Python 3, 67 bytes

```
print(bool(__import__('re').search(input(),open(__file__).read())))
```

Added after reading [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69203/quinean-regex-tester#comment168459_69203).

Comment: `int` is shorter than `bool`.

Answer (score 7):

## Julia, <s>64</s> 54 bytes

```
r=readline;show(ismatch(Regex(r()),open(r,@__FILE__)))
```

Julia regular expressions use PCRE. While reading the source code of the file is a standard loophole for quines, in this case it has been explicitly allowed. Takes input with no trailing newline.

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 22 bytes

```
"+Q ³sAJ fU"+Q ³sAJ fU
```

[Standard quine framework](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=IitRILNzN0oiK1Egs3M3Sg==&input=) with a few bytes added to fit this challenge. Truthy = match(es), falsy = null. [Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=IitRILNzQUogZlUiK1Egs3NBSiBmVQ==&input=Ii4rIg==)

```
         // Implicit: U = input string, A = 10, J = -1, Q = quotation mark
"..."+Q  // Take this string and concatenate a quotation mark.
³        // Repeat three times.
sAJ      // Slice off the first 10 and last 1 chars.
fU       // Match U to the result.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 21 bytes

```
open 0;$_=<0>=~$_
```

17 bytes plus 4 bytes for `-pl0`. Run like this:

```
echo open | perl -pl0 quinean
```

The source file must contain only the code above (no shebang, no trailing newline). Outputs `1` if the regex matches and the empty string if it doesn't (the empty string is falsey in Perl).

---

Four bytes can be saved if the input is guaranteed not to end in a newline:

```
open 0;say<0>=~<>
```

Run like this:

```
echo -n open | perl -M5.010 quinean
```

`say` requires Perl 5.10+ and must be enabled with `-M5.010`. According to [Meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/274/31388), "the `-M5.010`, when needed, is free," giving a score of 17 bytes.

### How it works

This is a simple variation on the standard "cheating" quine:

```
open 0;print<0>
```

This opens the file named in `$0` and reads the contents with `<0>`.

`$_=<0>=~$_` reads one line from the source file, does a regex match against the contents of `$_` (which were read by the `-p` flag), and assigns the result to `$_`. `-p` prints `$_` automatically at the end.

Answer (score 2):

## Jolf, <s>18</s> 15 bytes

Supports the JS flavour of RegEx, I hope that's okay. [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=IGgiJSIkY29kZS52YWx1ZSNp).

```
 h$code.value#i
```

Commented:

```
  $code.value#      the document's element "code" (the program container)
_h            i     and output if it has (matches) the input string (i.e. regex)
```

Comment: In which browser does this work? Both Chrome and Firefox complain that `x.step` is not a function.

Comment: @Dennis Huh. I must have broken the interpreter last night. What else is wrong? I currently am unable to debug, am at school.

Comment: Good. Now add a shortcut to the document's element "code" so we can make it shorter.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ It also gives a reference error for `math`.

Comment: @Dennis Ah, that's why. I forgot to update the HTML, I added math.js. I will revise when I arrive home, if that's not too late. (In about 4 ish hours)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 63 bytes

```
StringMatchQ[ToString[#0, InputForm], RegularExpression[#1]] &
```

Note the trailing space. Uses the standard Mma quine mechanism, and tests if it matches the regex.

Answer (score 1):

## , 14 chars / 26 bytes (non-competitive)

```
⟮‼(ⒸⅩ222+ᶈ0)đï
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=false&input=%5E%E2%85%A9222&code=%E2%9F%AE%E2%80%BC%28%E2%92%B8%E2%85%A9222%2B%E1%B6%880%29%C4%91%C3%AF)</kbd>

Using a version with bug fixes written after the challenge.

## Explanation

```
⟮‼(ⒸⅩ222+ᶈ0)đï // implicit: ï=input
⟮               // copy block: copy following code for later use
 (ⒸⅩ222+ᶈ0)   // take convert 10222 to char, add stuff inside copy block
‼           đï // check if input matches resulting string
               // implicit output
```

NOTE: Copy blocks are NOT quine operators. They are meant to be more versatile alternatives to variable declarations.

Comment: I think you can save a byte by changing `Ⅹ` to 10.